# How to get rid of grub when deleted partition

Tags: dual-boot

I had Linux installed but decided I didn't want it. So I deleted the partition that contained Linux in Windows 10. And when I turn my pc on it comes to the grub command line. I am trying to figure out how to boot from usb so I can fix it in Windows 10. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi)

Comment: I would suggest it the other way round @David Foerster because the answer there isn't a very permanent fix and may cause issues when reinstalling Ubuntu later.

Answer (score 0):

**Pro way:**

1. Boot into a Windows repair disk or Windows installer disk (your flash drive will do, you just need to make it bootable. I suggest using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10))
2. Once you're booted, you should see a window. If not, proceed to step 3. Configure keyboard and language.
3. It should prompt you to install Windows (Install Now button). Instead of proceeding, you should see "Repair computer" or something on the lower left corner of the window.
4. You should see a menu. Go to command prompt `(Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> Command prompt)`.
5. Run `bootrec /fixmbr`
6. Reboot. If it doesn't, leave a comment.

---

**Lazy way (Recommended):**

1. Follow steps 1 to 3 above.
2. Go to `Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> Startup repair`
3. Let it do its thing while you cross your fingers.